# How to get Data using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I want to get following data using Mongoose.

This is Schema structure:

```
title: {
    type: String,
},
deadline: {
    type: Number,(day)
},
date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
}
```

In above, "date" field represents start time.
**start time** = date
**end time** = date + 24 * 3600 * 1000 * deadline
I want to get data that current date is in between "start time" and "end time"
Please help me.

Comment: Are you asking to filter the collection so as to return only those documents where the date property is between the start and end time (as defined in your question)?

Comment: You can get start and end time from "date" field of schema.
"date" field represents created date.
So I want to get data where the current date is between start time and end time.

Comment: Hmm, that does not answer my question, and so I do not understand what your post is about.

Comment: Sorry, I answer your question, "Yes".
What do you want to know more?